# Loading ugly input

Tags: c++

I need to know how to load input like this in c++

```
{ [1, 1], [2, 10] , [-10, 20] }
```

In C i could write something like that:

```
if ( ( scanf(" %c",&bracket) ) != 1 || bracket != '{') {
    printf("Wrong input.\n");
    return 1;
} // 1st bracket


while(1) {

   if ( ( scanf(" %c%d%c%d%c",&bracket1,&arr[index][0],&dot,&arr[index][1],&bracket2) ) != 5  || bracket1 != '[' || bracket2 != ']' || dot != ',') {
       printf("Wrong input.\n");
       return 1;
   }

   if ( ( scanf(" %c",&tester) ) != 1 || ( tester != ',' && tester != '}' ) ) {
       printf("Wrong input.\n");
       return 1;
   }

   index++;

   if ( tester == '}' ) 
      break;

  }
```

But i have no idea how to load it in c++ and fix all the wrong inputs. I tried to load it with cin but it did not work and could not fix wrong inputs with cin.

Comment: Read up 'bout the member functions of [`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), of which `cin` is an instance. Just because there are other idioms in place, doesn't mean you can't check if the input is correct.

Comment: Showing us the C code that works, but not the C++ code that didn't work, makes it somewhat difficult to tell you *why* the C++ code didn't work. And in C++, input is usually handled by an `operator>>()` overload for the *class* that will eventually hold and handle the data. So to make a *good* answer, we'd have to guesstimate the data structure that would work best for your application, and implement a complete solution, class, input operator overload and everything...

Comment: Have a look to [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)

Comment: C code should work in C++ too!

Comment: Your sample is basically a list of pairs. If you do not want/need to parse the input, just ignore everything else except for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to break the input in tokens (or lexemes). Your input is made of 7 types of tokens: `[ ] { } , number end_of_file`.

A possible solution:

```
// tokens definition
enum token
{
  open_obj,
  close_obj,
  open_pair,
  close_pair,
  comma,
  number,
  end
};

// scanner
class scanner_type
{
  std::istream& mis;

public:

  token mt;
  int mn;

  scanner_type( std::istream& ais ) : mis( ais ) {}

  token get()
  {
    std::ws( mis ); // eat white

    char c;
    if ( ! mis.get( c ) )
      return mt = token::end;

    switch ( c )
    {
    case '[': return mt = token::open_pair;
    case ']': return mt = token::close_pair;
    case '{': return mt = token::open_obj;
    case '}': return mt = token::close_obj;
    case ',': return mt = token::comma;
    default:
      if ( std::isdigit( c ) || c == '-' || c == '+' )
      {
        mis.unget();
        mis >> mn;
        return mt = token::number;
      }
      else
      {
        throw "unexpected character";
      }
    };
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss( "{ [1, 1], [2, 10] , [-10, 20] }" );
  scanner_type sc( ss );

  assert( sc.get() == token::open_obj );
  assert( sc.get() == token::open_pair );
  assert( sc.get() == token::number );
  assert( sc.mn == 1 );
  // ...

  return 0;
}
```

Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) about scanners.