# Input pattern c++

Tags: c++, cin

Lets say i am given input

```
{ [1, 1], [2,10] , [-10, 20] }
```

I have to retrive number and check if the input is correct ( if "," isnt missing or if { and } are at the start/end )

In c, i could just use

```
scanf(" %c%d, %d%c",&zatvorka,&jedna,&dva,&zatvorka_dva);
```

In a while loop to scan the input , but how could i do it in c++? As far as i know , to `cin` is used to retrive data but it has no pattern like `scanf()` which would make it hard to retrieve data in such pattern and check if it is correct. How could i scan input like that ( for example) in c++?

Comment: the standard C I/O libraries are available in C++ as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin

Comment: im not sure if we will be allowed to use C I/O libraries... is scanf behavior possible with cin?

Comment: In that case, take the input as a string and call `stoi` to extract the relevant info

Comment: What's wrong with `cin >> brace1 >> num1 >> comma >> num2 >> brace2`?

Comment: If your latest lessons are about parsing, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35339635/1983409.

Comment: char curly_one;
    char zatvorka_one;
    int number;
    char comma;
    int number_two;
    char zatvorka_two;

    cin >> curly_one;
    while(cin >> zatvorka_one >> number >> comma >> number_two >> zatvorka_two){
        cout  << zatvorka_one << number << comma << number_two << zatvorka_two << endl;
    }
    return 0; i tried it @n.m. and with input i wrote it only printed [1,1]

Comment: There are commas between the pairs.

Comment: oh . it worked now , but how could idetect wrong input? If nothing was scanned ( for example last bracket is missing) or wrong input ( character instead of number / double instead if int) ? I tried to set cin.fail() condition right in the while loop but even inputing wrong input didnt invoke it.

Comment: @J.dd Could you accept my answer if it helped?

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function is available in C++ as well. You need to include the `cstdio` header file to access it.

More info:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Comment: I would say it is OK to use e.g. snprintf in C++ , but do not mix printf/scanf with iostreams in the same program. E.g. performance will suffer.